# ATI RS690m X1200 proprietary driver installation

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my emachine e625 AMD64 (TF-20) with an ATI RS690m X1200 graphics card but I didn't have 3D acceleration. The open-source driver works, except for any video effects or acceleration… I've downloaded the driver from [ATI](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Legacy/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.12&lang=English) and followed [the installation instructions](https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/674/9206/0/www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/linux_cat92-inst.pdf) and here is the result:

```
Error: ./default_policy.sh does not support version
default:v2:x86_64:lib32::none:3.0.0-17-generic; make sure that the version is being
correctly set by --iscurrentdistro
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to give a link to the download and a link to the installation instructions that you followed?

Answer (score 1):

The file that you downloaded is `ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run`. It is an executable file.

- Right click on the file, Properties, Permissions tab, check "Allow to run this file as a program".
- Then in a terminal, move to your download folder, probably by typing `cd ~/Downloads/`.
- In the same terminal window, launch `sudo ./ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run`.
- Follow the installation wizard.

Comment: @ Agmenor,
I followed also the steps mentionned in your answer (given also in the instruction PDF doc on ATI webpage)...the same message occures...thanks again for your help...

Comment: I am sorry but I personally don't know the answer. I hope that somebody else on this site does… Try looking for support directly from ATI if this question doesn't get answered. If they help you, please do not forget to post what helped you as an answer to your own question.