# Problem graphics with ATI Radeon x1270 (RS690M) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, ati

I'm Italian and so I apologize for my English!
I'm a beginner to Ubuntu and I tried it on my desktop PC and it's fantastic, fast and fun!

I decided to try it on my netbook Packard Bell DOT M/A and this is the configuration:

- AMD Athlon L110 1.2GHz
- 2GB of RAM
- ATI Radeon x1270 (RS690M)
- 150GB Hard Disk

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with Wubi (dualboot Windows 7 + Ubuntu 12.04), because the netbook does not have a DVD player!

During the installation everything is OK, after it was installed I see mistakes in the graphical display!
I see objects that are seen in different colors and moving (buttons, mouse pointer, text bar ... etc ...)
At one point came not to see anything, such as this screenshot:

[image]

The drivers are open, that is already installed in Ubuntu.
Windows 7 video card runs fine, can run well Aero (transparent window effects), I can watch movies in HD and play some games with the Catalyst drivers from AMD.
Now I ask a favor, you can help me solve this problem?
Is there a fix for this driver or drivers different on the Internet?
Thanks for your attention, good bye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets get through some steps,

Please download the graphics driver form [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Legacy/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.12&lang=English)

For installation see here [ATI RS690m X1200 proprietary driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128072/ati-rs690m-x1200-proprietary-driver-installation)

Please make sure following libraries are installed

- XFree86-Mesa-libGL
- libstdc++
- libgcc
- XFree86-libs
- fontconfig
- freetype
- zlib
- gcc

Comment: In the terminal gives me an error:
Error: ./default_policy.sh does not support version
default:v2:x86_64:lib32::none:3.0.0-17-generic; make sure that the version is being
correctly set by --iscurrentdistro.... How do I do?

Comment: make sure the libraries  are installed. I personaly never had ati grphics card. Alternatively in software center search for `fglrx` ,, then install `ATI binary X.Org driver` from search result.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Gateway L3103u Netbook with this exact same card and problem. The only fix I have ever found is by installing fglrx alongside the open source driver. While the card is not supported in the latest versions of Catalyst, the installation of the driver fixes whatever modeset is causing the buffer error (what I call the drawing of all of those lines).

Disabling modeset (with nomodeset) will also disable your ability to scale your framebuffer, but that might not be an issue for you.

Comment: nice. I have a LT3107. First tried nomodeset but that prevents ctrl+alt+F1-6 for console access. Installing fglrx worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same netbook with the same problem.

The proprietary drivers wont work because they only work with kernel `2.6.28` and older.

> ATI/AMD dropped Catalyst support for these cards in Catalyst 9-4. These cards are supported with the legacy ATI 9-3 Catalyst release, but you MUST use a kernel <= 2.6.28 and Xserver <= 1.5

So after a while, I found [**this**](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1989543.html).

You have to add `nomodeset` on `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

find the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

save the file and do

```
sudo update-grub
```

then reboot and you'll have your desktop.

The only thing that I can't find yet is how to enable the effects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you try Ubuntu from a Live USB just to see if this issue is still there when you run Ubuntu live or if it's something that appears when you install via Wubi. I know Wubi installs can be a bit dodgy sometimes, and issues might disappear if you actually do a "clean" install of Ubuntu on the hdd.

If you want to keep Windows, you can still choose this during the USB install and Ubuntu will create a separate partition for Ubuntu to use. Remember to backup all your data before experimenting with partitions, though!